# Encrypt a text field that is both ExternalID and Unique

Tags: externalid, platform-encryption, unique-field

I am trying to determine if this is possible - Encrypt a text field that is both Unique and an ExternalID.  Via deterministic encryption, I believe it is possible.  I am just wanting to see if anyone has tried it and been able to successfully do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_deterministic_considerations.htm&type=5) is quite clear on this

> External ID
>
> Case-insensitive deterministic encryption supports Text and Email external ID custom fields but not other external ID custom fields. When you create or edit these fields, use one of the following field setting combinations.

```
EXTERNAL ID     UNIQUE ATTRIBUTES           ENCRYPTED
Text            None                        Use case-insensitive deterministic encryption

Text            Unique and case sensitive   Use case-sensitive deterministic encryption

Text            Unique and case insensitive Use case-insensitive deterministic encryption

Email           None                        Use case-insensitive deterministic encryption

Email           Unique                      Use case-sensitive deterministic encryption
```

> You can’t save changes to both Unique - Case-Sensitive and Encrypted options at the same time. **Change one setting, save it, then change the next**.

I've done this in my org and it works fine